# Looping over Months not displaying the last month

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop over motnhs like.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="05-2012" to="12-2012" step="#createTimeSpan(31, 0, 0, 0)#">
        #LSDateFormat(i, "MMM")#  
</cfloop>
```

but it displays months only till Nov 2012. in order to display the Dec 2012 I have to put

```
#LSDateFormat(i, "MMM")#
```

again after the loop. any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this is because "12-2012" is "01-12-2012" and you are using 31 days step (which is not the same as one month). So last iteration is looking for 04-12-2012 while your "to" is 01-12-2012. You can easily see this problem like this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="05-2012" to="12-2012" step="#createTimeSpan(31, 0, 0, 0)#">
    #LSDateFormat(i)#<br/>
</cfloop>
```

Simple solution would be this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="#CreateDate(2012, 5, 1)#" to="#CreateDate(2012, 12, 31)#" step="#CreateTimeSpan(31, 0, 0, 0)#">
    #LSDateFormat(i)#<br/>
</cfloop>
```

Plus it looks a bit more readable for me.

Please note that in case of longer period problem may appear again. Most reliable solution would be to make the span equal to 1 month, say use something like this:

```
<cfset i = CreateDate(2012, 5, 1) />
<cfset stop = CreateDate(2012, 12, 31) />
<cfloop condition="i LTE stop">
    #LSDateFormat(i)#<br/>
    <cfset i = DateAdd("m",1,i)>
</cfloop>
```

See, it is always 1st day of the month.